# How to sort the result in Lucene.net in C#?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

i am adding special enum to lucene for relevant the search. how i can sort the result who have a specific enum value.

suppose i add Poor moderate Best and i need to get best first in result then how i can do this in Lucene.net.

any way to do this in Lucene.net

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lucene does have its own Sort. Look at the Namespace `Lucene.Net.Search.Sort`. Below is an example where I am sorting by DateOfMessage.

```
Lucene.Net.Search.TopDocsCollector collector = Lucene.Net.Search.TopScoreDocCollector.create(InternalMaxSearchResults, false); // default is relevance
var sortBy = new Lucene.Net.Search.Sort(new Lucene.Net.Search.SortField(SearchIndex.IndexFields.DateOfMessage.ToString(), Lucene.Net.Search.SortField.LONG, true));
collector = Lucene.Net.Search.TopFieldCollector.create(
    sortBy,
    InternalMaxSearchResults,   /* max 500 results */
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false);
    break;

// search with the collector
searcher.Search(queryMain, collector);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "SimpleFacetedSearch" to categorize the results as poor, moderate, best
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/LUCENENET/Simple+Faceted+Search